# How to get the invoking target of makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu, gnu-make

How to get the invoking target of the GNU make Makefile?

for example, I invoke `make` with the following command line:

```
make a-target
```

How can I get the invoking target "a-target" in the Makefile and assign it to a variable?

Further more, if more than one target is specified on the command line:

```
make target1 target2 ...
```

How do I get all of them?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The variable [`MAKECMDGOALS`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Goals.html) contains the list of targets that were specified on the command line, no matter how many (it's empty if there were none).

Answer (score 21):

Maybe you need `$@`?

See http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables for more details.

Comment: $@ is the current target, not the target that was specified on the command line as in the original question.